# ObjectをJSON.stringfyしてpostするとエスケープシークエンスがつき、使用できなくなる

Tags: javascript, json

フロント側からサーバに

```
{"type":"flex","altText":"Flex Message","contents":{"type":"carousel","contents":[{"type":"bubble","direction":"ltr","hero":{"type":"image","url":"URL","align":"start","size":"full","aspectRatio":"1:1","aspectMode":"cover"},"footer":{"type":"box","layout":"horizontal","contents":[{"type":"button","action":{"type":"uri","label":"Button","uri":"URL2"}}]}}]}}
```

というObjectをAPIに使う目的で送信したいのですが、Objectはそのままpostできなかったため、一度JSON.stringfyしてからサーバにpostします。
サーバ側で`console.log(req.body)`を出力すると表示上は正常なのですが、API等で値を渡そうとすると

```
{\\"type\\":\\"flex\\",\\"altText\\":\\"Flex Message\\",\\"contents\\":{\\"type\\":\\"carousel\\",\\"contents\\":[{\\"type\\":\\"bubble\\",\\"direction\\":\\"ltr\\",\\"hero\\":{\\"type\\":\\"image\\",\\"url\\":\\"URL\\",\\"align\\":\\"start\\",\\"size\\":\\"full\\",\\"aspectRatio\\":\\"1:1\\",\\"aspectMode\\":\\"cover\\"},\\"footer\\":{\\"type\\":\\"box\\",\\"layout\\":\\"horizontal\\",\\"contents\\":[{\\"type\\":\\"button\\",\\"action\\":{\\"type\\":\\"uri\\",\\"label\\":\\"Button\\",\\"uri\\":\\"URL2\\"}}]}}]}}
```

のように大量のエスケープシークエンスがついてしまいます。
元の配列に戻すためunescape()関数を使用しても正常にならず、困っております。

知りたい点として、今自分は

1. Objectをサーバにpostする方法を間違えている
2. JSONをAPI等でstrとして使う方法を間違えている

どちらになるのでしょうか？
原因がどこにあるのか自分でわかっていないため、適合する内容も見つけられずに困っております。ご助言いただけると助かります。

**追記**
失礼しました。expressで
1)フロント側post

```
$.post({
　　url: "/{post_path}",
　　data: {post_data}
})
```

2)サーバ側受信

```
app.post("/{post_path}", function (req, res, next) {
    var { 各パラメータ } = req.body;
　　APIfunction(req.body)
```

の様な形でやりとりしております。
APIはLINE APIでpush(Flex)を送っております。

[Messaging APIリファレンス - Flex Message | LINE Developers](https://developers.line.biz/ja/reference/messaging-api/#flex-message)

Comment: もっと説明が必要です。stringify()の結果をどうやってPOSTしているのか、req.bodyとは何なのか、APIとはなんなのか、req.bodyをどうやってAPIに渡しているのか、エスケープされた結果はどうやって確認したのか、など。

Comment: ブラウザ → サーバー → LINE の2回 JSON をPOSTしているということですか？ それで [下のコメント](#comment59236_55223) でサーバまでは期待した状態であるということなら、LINE API へのPOST処理について具体的なコードとその結果があると、答えが得られやすいのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express ウェブフレームワークを使っているというのが一番重要な情報でしたね。 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005939/how-do-i-consume-the-json-post-data-in-an-express-application が見つかりました。

Express のバージョン 4.16 以上なら、[`express.json()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json) を使うことで `req.body` がオブジェクトになるようです。

ついでに `curl` コマンドで期待する形式でPOSTしたり、ブラウザで実際POSTデータがどうなっているのかを確認できるとこれからの開発に役立つでしょう。

ブラウザ開発者ツールの `Network` タブ → 該当のリクエストを選択 →

1. `Headers` → `Request headers` の `Content-Type` が application/json などサーバーが期待する値になっていること
2. （Firefoxの場合）`Params` で JSON のところ，（Chromeの場合）`Headers` の下の `Request Payload` のところ
   [image: ChromeでJSONをPOSTしているのを確認する]
   に内容が表示されていること

Comment: ありがとうございます。express.jsonの元となるbody-parserは使用しており、Content-Type は application/json になっているのも確認しました。

サーバ側で受信したjsonをconsole.log()で出力すると正常に受け取れているのですが、LINEAPIでその値を使うと上記の様にエスケープシークエンスが大量についてしまいます。
API単体で送信したいJSONを文字列として手入力した場合は正常に動作することを確認しています。

Comment: APIではObjectで送るべきところをstringで送信しているのが原因でした。ありがとうございました。